# Pixi - how to continue an animation when focus is lost?

Tags: pixi.js

I have a pixi graphic, which I animate.

I would like the animation ton continue even when the browser is minimised or the tab is no longer the "active" tab.

How do I do this? Currently all animation is paused when the browser focus is lost?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do about this, really. The ticker used in pixi uses requestAnimationFrame, which is the browser api that allows you to setup a callback each time the browser wants to draw to the screen. On most monitors, therefore, the callback occurs 60 times a second. But to save cpu and battery, if the window is minimized the requestAnimationFrame won't be sent by the browser, thus causing your animation to pause.

There's nothing you can do to change this browser behaviour.

You could link updating animations to a setInterval I guess, but browsers also throttle any window timeouts these days on a minimized window, again for cpu and battery saving reasons

Answer (score 0):

You can render the stage at any time by calling;

```
 renderer.render(stage);
```

You will have to call this in something like [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), rather than [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) in order for the animation to continue when the page is not active.